# I have these tables created from longtable, why don't they have the same width?

Tags: longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{Table Sample}
\author{Nimish Mistry}
\date{July 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{2 column table}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    A & B \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\section{3 column table}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.33\textwidth}|p{0.33\textwidth}|p{0.33\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\section{4 column table}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\section{4 column table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! probably because you have different numbers of columns and consequesntly diferent numbers of vertical lines and `tabcolsep` spaces

Comment: I'm using Sharelatex, compiled just once!

Comment: Then how do I ensure that my tables have the same width?

Comment: Maybe first try to follow the advice and compile twice :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, sorry that did not work!

Comment: That's ok. But it helps if you give feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have different numbers of columns and consequently different numbers of vertical lines and `\tabcolsep` spaces, you need in determining of column width to consider width of vertical lines and `\tabcolsep` spaces.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, longtable}% added array, as suggest David in hos comment below

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}} % calculation of column width
    \hline
    A & B \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.33\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Firs solution has wrong calculated tabular width (see comment of David Carlisle below. Considering it the code above is accordingly corrected. As proof se image below:

[image]

which is generated by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{22pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth)\relax}|}} % calculation of column width
    \hline
    A & B \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|*{3}{p{\dimexpr0.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.33\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you to point on errors in my answer. I correct it now.

Answer (score 1):

When you does not need to repeat the header of the table at beginning of next pages (the core function of `longtable` package) and when you supposes only short texts in table cells (no multiline paragraphs) then you need not to calculate cell widths manually. You can use the primitive construct `\hbox to\hsize` combined by `\hfil` in each cell.

```
\def\ta|{\hbox to\hsize \bgroup \vrule height12pt depth5pt \taA}
\def\taA{\futurelet\next\taB}
\def\taB{\ifx\next\relax\egroup \else \expandafter\taC \fi}
\def\taC#1|{\quad\rlap{#1}\hfil\vrule \taA}

\hrule
\ta |A|B|C|\relax
\hrule

\medskip

\hrule
\ta |A|B|\relax
\hrule

\medskip

\hrule
\ta |A|B|C|D|\relax
\hrule

\bye
```